# Printing message only once after iterating through the first column of a 2d array

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Grade{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String students[][] = new String[2][4];

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        System.out.print("\n\nStudent 00" + (i + 1) + "\n\n");

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

            if (j == 0) {
                System.out.print("\n\tStudent Code : ");
            } else if (j == 1) {
                System.out.print("\n\tName : ");
            } else if (j == 2) {
                System.out.print("\n\tMaths Grade : ");
            } else if (j == 3) {
                System.out.print("\n\tFrench Grade : ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("\n\tNonexistent field!\n");
            }

            students[i][j] = input.nextLine();
        }

    }

    System.out.print("\n\tRegistered Students : \n\n");

    System.out.print("\tCODE\tFULL NAME\tMATHS\tFRENCH\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

            System.out.print("\t" + students[i][j] + "  ");

        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

//Ask for student code.

```
    System.out.print("\n\tStudent Code : ");

    String search= input.nextLine();

    boolean found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
```

//          found= true;

```
            if (search.equals(students[i][0])) {

                found = true;

                System.out.print("\n\tStudent Code Found!\n");

                String math = students[i][2];
                String french = students[i][3];

                Double m = new Double(math);
                double mathConv = m.doubleValue();

                Double f = new Double(french);
                double frenchConv = f.doubleValue();

                double average = (mathConv + frenchConv) / 2;

                System.out.print("\n\tMoyenne de l'etudiant : " + average + "\n");

                if (average <= 40) {

                    System.out.print("\n\tFailure!\n");

                } else if (average > 40 && average < 70) {

                    System.out.print("\n\tReprisal!\n");

                } else {

                    System.out.print("\n\tSuccess!\n");
                }

            }

            else if (!search.equals(students[i][0])) {

                found = false;

                System.out.print("\n\tCode incorrect!\n");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

I need to display only one message after entering the code etudiant but istead it displays the message 4 times. The loop should only iterate through the first column of each line and compares it to what the user entered.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
```

to this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
```

as we want to run that loop only once.

Alternatively, you can remove the j loop altogether.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate for the search you don't need the second loop to iterate over the attributes, because you don't use it

```java
 System.out.print("\n\tStudent Code : ");
 String search = input.nextLine();
 boolean found = false;

 for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
//        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) { //you don't need this loop
```

Comment: Thanks. But it still prints "code incorrect" before "code correct" when I enter the code for the second student.

Comment: When you've found the student - stop iterating by adding `if (found) break;` at the end of the search loop

Answer (score 0):

it's recommended you use the length argument for those arrays, that way if you ever change the size, the loop won't break, in this case you can just get the first element of the array, and then iterate through that. So intead of

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        System.out.print("\n\nStudent 00" + (i + 1) + "\n\n");

        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {

            if (j == 0) {
                System.out.print("\n\tStudent Code : ");
            } else if (j == 1) {
                System.out.print("\n\tName : ");
            } else if (j == 2) {
                System.out.print("\n\tMaths Grade : ");
            } else if (j == 3) {
                System.out.print("\n\tFrench Grade : ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("\n\tNonexistent field!\n");
            }

            students[i][j] = input.nextLine();
        }

    }
```

you can say

```
        System.out.print("\n\nStudent 001" + "\n\n");

        for (int j = 0; j < students[0].length; j++) {

            if (j == 0) {
                System.out.print("\n\tStudent Code : ");
            } else if (j == 1) {
                System.out.print("\n\tName : ");
            } else if (j == 2) {
                System.out.print("\n\tMaths Grade : ");
            } else if (j == 3) {
                System.out.print("\n\tFrench Grade : ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("\n\tNonexistent field!\n");
            }

            students[0][j] = input.nextLine();
        }
```